# Setting blank thumbnail while sharing links on Facebook or Linkedin

Tags: facebook, blogger

One of the problems I face while sharing a link of my blogger post on facebook or linkedin is that the thumbnail shared is my picture (which is the only picture on the page). I would prefer no thumbnail being shared.I tried using

```
<meta property="og:image" content=""
```

I.e the content is kept as blank, yet it shows a thumbnail. How do i set it to no picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Facebook/Linkedin will crawl your site and decide on it's own what images to offer the user. The `og:image` meta tag is just a suggestion and not a directive.

The only way to share without image is for the user to remove it.

Update: there is another way. You could detect (on the server) FB/LinkedIns crawler and serve them HTML that does not contain any images. That way they wouldn't have anything to display (just text). I don't know if that's possible on blogger. And if you go down this path, check FB/LinkedIn's TOS if this is allowed (doing this with google, for instance, will get you banned).